# What is the implication of exportjars := true?

Tags: javafx, sbt, scalafx

I've just started using an sbt plugin for packaging JavaFx/ScalaFx applications [sbt-javafx](https://github.com/kavedaa/sbt-javafx). This under Java 7.

While the plugin seems to work pretty well, it is not able to properly package multi-module project. A workaround they have found is to use `exportsJars := true` in all the modules on which the JavaFX  modules depends on.

I also have IntelliJ IDEA that can produce a JavaFX application for me, though that would break the automated build. I'd very much like to have the executable automated.

I need to understand the broad implication of that parameter on my sbt build. Why is the setting needed to be `true`?

Here is the help definition:

> Determines whether the exported classpath for this project contains classes (false) or a packaged jar (true).

It sounds like by default it's `false`. Why?

p.s. If someone has a cleaner solution to package JavaFX/ScalaFX applications using sbt, please feel free to share.

Comment: This question is a bit old, but just in case... FYI, I have [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/kavedaa/sbt-javafx/pull/17) to the sbt-javafx maintainer with a proposed fix for packaging multi-module projects without exporting jars. Feel free to try it out for yourself in the meantime.